# Sum cells depending on what year your in

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create a Excel code which calculate the year-to-date of a column of data. [image]

I would like to create a code which does the following:

```
In 2nd row the value in C2 should be 382, 
in 3rd row the value of C3 should be B2+B3 = 547+165 = 547, 
in 4th row the value of C4 should be B2+B3+B4 = 382 + 165 + 189 = 736, 
in the 5th row the value of C5 should be B5 (because a new year is started), 
...
in the 17th row the value of C17 should be B5 + B6 + ... B17 = 3765,
in the 18th row the value of C18 should be B18 (because a new year starts)
```

I tried to make like a

```
=IF(YEAR(A2)=YEAR(A3);SUM($B$2:B3);B2)
```

But this is very inconsistent.

Comment: Did you try `SUMIFS()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `SUMIFS()`.

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:B2,$A$2:A2,">="&DATE(YEAR(A2),1,1),$A$2:A2,"<="&DATE(YEAR(A2),12,31))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two alternative methods, one using the fill down, another using dynamic arrays to spill!

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=SUM(B2:INDEX(B$2:B2,XMATCH(TEXTBEFORE(A2,"-")/1,TEXTBEFORE(A$2:A2,"-")/1)))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=MMULT(N(ROW(A2:A23)>=TOROW(ROW(A2:A23)))*N(TEXTBEFORE(A2:A23,"-")/1=TOROW(TEXTBEFORE(A2:A23,"-")/1)),B2:B23)
```

---

Using <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> helper functions.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=MAP(A2:A23,B2:B23,LAMBDA(α,φ,SUM(φ:INDEX(B$2:φ,
 XMATCH(TEXTBEFORE(α,"-")/1,TEXTBEFORE(A$2:α,"-")/1)))))
```

---

Also if you don't hesitate in using helper columns then it would be more simpler using <kbd>SUMIFS()</kbd>, the helper column can be hidden later.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A2</kbd>

```
=--TEXTBEFORE(B2:B23,"-")
```

---

And Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd> which needs to fill down!

```
=SUMIFS(C$2:C2,A$2:A2,A2)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

`=MAP(A2:A23,B2:B23,LAMBDA(X,Y,SUM((YEAR(A2:X)=YEAR(X))*B2:Y)))`

[image]

Or `=MMULT((YEAR(TOROW(A2:A23))=YEAR(A2:A23))*(TOROW(ROW(A2:A23))<=ROW(A2:A23)),B2:B23)`

Or the SUMIFS as Mayukh posted.